# RGBA Pixel Addition Alpha Value in Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, alpha

I'm working with an `HTML` `canvas` element, trying to draw shapes with opacity into it and then colorize them based on their opacity. For instance, I might draw a square with `rgba(0,0,0,.5)` and another one overlapping it with `rgba(100, 100, 100, .5)`. My question is: What effect does overlapping have on the `alpha` value? Obviously, an `a:.5` on top of an `a:.5` would not produce `a:1`... is there a formula for this? How does it work?

Comment: Aren't they simply (inversed) multiplied, so `.5×.5=.25`, and combined opacity becomes `1-.25=.75` ?

Comment: https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#canvascompositingandblending

Comment: That makes total sense, why it didn't occur to me...I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the formulas for how alpha blending and composition works can be found in the specs:

https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#canvascompositingandblending

Alpha channels are multiplied (see the alpha blending formula in the link) so they won't add up to 1.

I.e. (source: ibid):

```
co = Cs x αs + Cb x αb x (1 - αs)
```

Where

```
co: the premultiplied pixel value after compositing
Cs: the color value of the source graphic element being composited
αs: the alpha value of the source graphic element being composited
Cb: the color value of the backdrop
αb: the alpha value of the backdrop
```